# Collision Detection between Accelerating Spheres

Tags: math, 3d, simulation, physics, collision-detection

I am writing a physics engine/simulator which incorporates 3D space flight, planetary/stellar gravitation, ship thrust and relativistic effects.  So far, it is going very well, however, one thing that I need help with is the math of the collision detection algorithm.

The iterative simulation of movement that I am using is basically as follows:

(Note: 3D Vectors are ALL CAPS.)

```
For each obj

    obj.ACC = Sum(all acceleration influences)

    obj.POS = obj.POS + (obj.VEL * dT) + (obj.ACC * dT^2)/2     (*EQ.2*)

    obj.VEL = obj.VEL + (obj.ACC * dT)

Next
```

Where:

```
obj.ACC is the acceleration vector of the object
obj.POS is the position or location vector of the object
obj.VEL is the velocity vector of the object

obj.Radius is the radius (scalar) of the object

dT is the time delta or increment
```

What I basically need to do is to find some efficient formula that derives from (*EQ.2*) above for two objects (obj1, obj2) and tell if they ever collide, and if so, at what time.  I need the exact time both so that I can determine if it is in this particular time increment (because acceleration will be different at different time increments) and also so that I can locate the exact position (which I know how to do, given the time)

For this engine, I am modelling all objects as spheres, all this formula/algorithm needs to do is to figure out at what points:

```
(obj1.POS - obj2.POS).Distance = (obj1.Radius + obj2.Radius)
```

where .Distance is a positive scalar value.  (You can also square both sides if this is easier, to avoid the square root function implicit in the .Distance calculation).

(yes, I am aware of many, many other collision detection questions, however, their solutions all seem to be very particular to their engine and assumptions, and none appear to match my conditions: 3D, spheres, and acceleration applied within the simulation increments.  Let me know if I am wrong.)

---

Some Clarifications:

1) It is not sufficient for me to check for *Intersection* of the two spheres before and after the time increment.  In many cases their velocities and position changes will far exceed their radii.

2) RE: efficiency, I do not need help (at this point anyway) with respect to determine likely candidates for collisions, I think that I have that covered.

---

Another clarification, which seems to be coming up a lot:

3) My equation (*EQ.2*) of incremental movement is a quadratic equation that applies both Velocity *and* Acceleration:

```
obj.POS = obj.POS + (obj.VEL * dT) + (obj.ACC * dT^2)/2
```

In the physics engines that I have seen, (and certainly every game engine that I ever heard of) only *linear* equations of incremental movement that apply *only* Velocity:

```
obj.POS = obj.POS + (obj.VEL * dT)
```

This is why I cannot use the commonly published solutions for collision detection found on StackOverflow, on Wikipedia and all over the Web, such as finding the intersection/closest approach of two line segments.  My simulation deals with variable accelerations that are fundamental to the results, so what I need is the intersection/closest approach of two *parabolic* segments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the webpage AShelley referred to, the Closest Point of Approach method is developed for the case of two objects moving at constant velocity. However, I believe the same vector-calculus method can be used to derive a result in the case of two objects both moving with constant non-zero acceleration (quadratic time dependence).

In this case, the time derivative of the distance-squared function is 3rd order (cubic) instead of 1st order. Therefore there will be 3 solutions to the Time of Closest Approach, which is not surprising since the path of both objects is curved so multiple intersections are possible. For this application, you would probably want to use the earliest value of t which is within the interval defined by the current simulation step (if such a time exists).

I worked out the derivative equation which should give the times of closest approach:

`0 = |D_ACC|^2 * t^3 + 3 * dot(D_ACC, D_VEL) * t^2 + 2 * [ |D_VEL|^2 + dot(D_POS, D_ACC) ] * t + 2 * dot(D_POS, D_VEL)`

where:

`D_ACC = ob1.ACC-obj2.ACC`

`D_VEL = ob1.VEL-obj2.VEL` (before update)

`D_POS = ob1.POS-obj2.POS` (also before update)

and `dot(A, B) = A.x*B.x + A.y*B.y + A.z*B.z`

(Note that the square of the magnitude `|A|^2` can be computed using `dot(A, A)`)

To solve this for **t**, you'll probably need to use formulas like the ones [found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots).

Of course, this will only give you the moment of *closest approach*. You will need to test the distance at this moment (using something like Eq. 2). If it is greater than `(obj1.Radius + obj2.Radius)`, it can be disregarded (i.e. no collision). However, if the distance is less, that means the spheres collide before this moment. You could then use an iterative search to test the distance at earlier times. It might also be possible to come up with another (even more complicated) derivation which takes the size into account, or possible to find some other analytic solution, without resorting to iterative solving.

**Edit**: because of the higher order, some of the solutions to the equation are actually moments of *farthest separation*. I believe in all cases either 1 of the 3 solutions or 2 of the 3 solutions will be a time of farthest separation. You can test analytically whether you're at a min or a max by evaluating the second derivative with respect to time (at the values of t which you found by setting the first derivative to zero):

`D''(t) = 3 * |D_ACC|^2 * t^2 + 6 * dot(D_ACC, D_VEL) * t + 2 * [ |D_VEL|^2 + dot(D_POS, D_ACC) ]`

If the second derivative evaluates to a positive number, then you know the distance is at a minimum, not a maximum, for the given time t.

Comment: thanks tcovo, this is a good start on exactly what I need.  Any idea how to extend the cubic equation solution at Wikipedia to vector coefficients?

Comment: The cubic equation I wrote has scalar coefficients: the dot product of two vectors is a scalar, and the square of the magnitude is also a scalar. I edited my response to elaborate on those.

Comment: I tested the math on some simple cases and found (1) a typo and (2) that the solution to the derivative equation might find the times of farthest separation, which is not what we're looking for (not surprising, since setting the derivative to zero finds extrema, in general). I edited my response.

Comment: Consider using inequalities to conservatively eliminate the common case:  if |p1-p0| - |v1-v0|t - |a1-a0|t^2/2 > r1+r2 then there is no risk of collision.

Comment: Re. EDIT: Ah, that makes more sense.  I had been wondering about that odd asymmetry in the first-order term of the cubic equation.

Comment: Re: Farthest separation: yep, I knew this.  Other things that have to be checked include the solutions for (t) being outside the range of the current time increment, and it starting (or ending) in a collision state (i.e., boundary/initial conditions).

Comment: comingstorm:  good example, but I was hoping for a test that could avoid the SquareRoot() implicit in the distance ("|vector|") calculation. I.e., Something based on Distance^2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a line between the start location and end location of each sphere. If the resulting line segments intersect the spheres definitely collided at some point and some clever math can find at what time the collision occurred. Also make sure to check if the minimum distance between the segments (if they don't intersect) is ever less than 2*radius. This will also indicate a collision.

From there you can backstep your delta time to happen exactly at collision so you can correctly calculate the forces.

Have you considered using a physics library which already does this work? Many libraries use far more advanced and more stable (better integrators) systems for solving the systems of equations you're working with. [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) comes to mind.

Comment: Again, "Line Segments" assumes that my equation of incremental movement is: ( obj.POS = obj.POS * (obj.VEL * dT) }, which is *Linear*.  My incremental movement equation is *Quadratic*, which requires solving for the minimum separation of "Parabolic Segments".  It requires a completely different (and more difficult) formula.

Comment: I am not considering using someone else's physics library because one of my main goals is to do this myself.  Additionally, my brief survey of Open Source physics engines did not turn up any that adequately dealt with either object accelerations that varied with the inverse square of their distance (i.e., planetary Gravity, they all assume constant acceleration, at best) or with speed-limited effects and visibility propagation (i.e., the speed of light/relativity), nor any reasonable way too add them on.  Both of these are necessary for my simulation.

Comment: I don't know how accurate you're trying to be ... for a small enough dt can you treat the delta position as line segment?

Answer (score 2):

op asked for time of collision. A slightly different approach will compute it exactly...

Remember that the position projection equation is:

`NEW_POS=POS+VEL*t+(ACC*t^2)/2`

If we replace `POS` with `D_POS=POS_A-POS_B`, `VEL` with `D_VEL=VEL_A-VEL_B`, and `ACC=ACC_A-ACC_B` for objects `A` and `B` we get:

`$D_NEW_POS=D_POS+D_VEL*t+(D_ACC*t^2)/2`

This is the formula for vectored distance between the objects. In order to get the squared scalar distance between them, we can take the square of this equation, which after expansion looks like:

`distsq(t) = D_POS^2+2*dot(D_POS,D_VEL)*t + (dot(D_POS, D_ACC)+D_VEL^2)*t^2 + dot(D_VEL,D_ACC)*t^3 + D_ACC^2*t^4/4`

In order to find the time where collision occurs, we can set the equation equal to the square of the sum of radii and solve for `t`:

`0 = D_POS^2-(r_A+r_B)^2 + 2*dot(D_POS,D_VEL)*t + (dot(D_POS, D_ACC)+D_VEL^2)*t^2 + dot(D_VEL,D_ACC)*t^3 + D_ACC^2*t^4/4`

Now, we can solve for the equation using the [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation).

The quartic formula will yield 4 roots, but we are only interested in *real* roots. If there is a double real root, then the two objects touch edges at exactly one point in time. If there are two real roots, then the objects continuously overlap between root 1 and root 2 (i.e. root 1 is the time when collision starts and root 2 is the time when collision stops). Four real roots means that the objects collide twice, continuously between root pairs 1,2 and 3,4.

In R, I used `polyroot()` to solve as follows:

```
# initial positions
POS_A=matrix(c(0,0),2,1)
POS_B=matrix(c(2,0),2,1)
# initial velocities
VEL_A=matrix(c(sqrt(2)/2,sqrt(2)/2),2,1)
VEL_B=matrix(c(-sqrt(2)/2,sqrt(2)/2),2,1)
# acceleration
ACC_A=matrix(c(sqrt(2)/2,sqrt(2)/2),2,1)
ACC_B=matrix(c(0,0),2,1)
# radii
r_A=.25
r_B=.25
# deltas
D_POS=POS_B-POS_A
D_VEL=VEL_B-VEL_A
D_ACC=ACC_B-ACC_A


# quartic coefficients
z=c(t(D_POS)%*%D_POS-r*r, 2*t(D_POS)%*%D_VEL, t(D_VEL)%*%D_VEL+t(D_POS)%*%D_ACC, t(D_ACC)%*%D_VEL, .25*(t(D_ACC)%*%D_ACC))
# get roots
roots=polyroot(z)
# In this case there are only two real roots...
root1=as.numeric(roots[1])
root2=as.numeric(roots[2])

# trajectory over time
pos=function(p,v,a,t){
  T=t(matrix(t,length(t),2))
  return(t(matrix(p,2,length(t))+matrix(v,2,length(t))*T+.5*matrix(a,2,length(t))*T*T))
}

# plot A in red and B in blue
t=seq(0,2,by=.1) # from 0 to 2 seconds.
a1=pos(POS_A,VEL_A,ACC_A,t)
a2=pos(POS_B,VEL_B,ACC_B,t)
plot(a1,type='o',col='red')
lines(a2,type='o',col='blue')

# points of a circle with center 'p' and radius 'r'
circle=function(p,r,s=36){
  e=matrix(0,s+1,2)
  for(i in 1:s){
    e[i,1]=cos(2*pi*(1/s)*i)*r+p[1]
    e[i,2]=sin(2*pi*(1/s)*i)*r+p[2]
  }
  e[s+1,]=e[1,]
  return(e)
}

# plot circles with radius r_A and r_B at time of collision start in black
lines(circle(pos(POS_A,VEL_A,ACC_A,root1),r_A))
lines(circle(pos(POS_B,VEL_B,ACC_B,root1),r_B))
# plot circles with radius r_A and r_B at time of collision stop in gray
lines(circle(pos(POS_A,VEL_A,ACC_A,root2),r_A),col='gray')
lines(circle(pos(POS_B,VEL_B,ACC_B,root2),r_B),col='gray')
```

[image: Resulting R plot showing trajectories and start/stop collision location of objects]

Object `A` follows the red trajectory from the lower left to the upper right. Object `B` follows the blue trajectory from the lower right to the upper left. The two objects collide continuously between time 0.9194381 and time 1.167549. The two black circles just touch, showing the beginning of overlap - and overlap continues in time until the objects reach the location of the gray circles.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want the [Closest Point of Approach (CPA)](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0106/algorithm_0106.htm#Closest%20Point%20of%20Approach).  If it is less than the sum of the radiuses, you have a collision.   There is example code in the link.  You can calculate each frame with the current velocity, and check if the CPA time is less than your tick size.   You could even cache the cpa time, and only update when acceleration was applied to either item.

Comment: Yes, I know this method.  Unfortunately, AFAIK it does NOT solve for my equation 2 (i.e., with acceleration), it only solves for the incremental application of Velocity to the objects.  My engine uses the incremental application of Velocity AND Acceleration to the objects and thus requires a different (higher-order) formula to solve it.

Comment: How long is your tick (dT)?  For most simulations I've seen, it's small enough that the `(obj.ACC * dT^2)/2` term is negligable for any single tick, at least for the purposes of collision detection.

Comment: The ticks are 1/10th second right now, but that's parameterizable and could change.  Worse is the fact that accelerations of over 100 G's are both possible and at times likely.